# text vertical align in select box - firefox issue

Tags: firefox, select, vertical-alignment, css

I've got a problem with vertical align of select box caption in Firefox.

[image: screen from Firefox]

CSS for select looks like this:

```
select#cities_list {
    width: 95px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background: url('./img/select-arrow.png') no-repeat right transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

In Chrome everything looks fine:

[image]

Help!

Comment: Hi forkie, Did you get this issue fixed? If yes, then please help me..!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try this

```
padding:.3em;/.4em;
```

depending on your configuration.

Comment: What the heck is that?  I just tried this and it worked for the most part. What is this hack?

Comment: although I have no clue why this works... just as an fyi you can also say something like: padding:.3em .4em .3em .7em;/0; and it seems to work.

Comment: The "em" is "font-relative" notation (dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#em-unit). So what you are doing with that is just setting the padding to have a font-size-relative size. This is the same sort of hack, imo, than just setting the padding for 5px (for example). It is less ugly than having the text right in the top, but it is still not perfect as the scroll button gets smaller.  Besides it affects the horizontal padding, which you don't need. If you have to use this, do `padding: 0 .3em;`

Answer (score 1):

Another method, one that I prefer, is this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    select {
        padding-top: 8px;
    }
}
```

Set the `padding-top` to whatever you like. Anything within the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` brackets will execute on Firefox only.

Comment: Is this a hack? Will this endure on future firefox versions? I applied padding-top: 4px to the select input and it solves the issue. It seems that the select button does change it's vertical position only on firefox, but I'm concerned that some future browser or a non tested browser will not be aligned due to the 4px padding-top. What would you say about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just here to add that `@-moz-document url-prefix()` still works on the most recent version of Firefox at the time of writing; Firefox 61